# Different zooms in cropped image- LSTM image classification

Tags: computer-vision, lstm, crop, face

I have the problem that while cropping face images (with the same output size 256x256) the face looks bigger in some images than in another ones(the others have more background and less face). I want this images for training a LSTM, so it is this different face's sizes a problem for the training?

Thank you,

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask lots of useful tips on writing good questions.  I think you will get better answers if you update this with some of the advice there!

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do it